# Does Kha'zix's stealth work vs. towers?

Tags: league-of-legends

Normally all my expertise in the mechanics of LoL would discount this as NO before it even began as a question. However my friend claims MULTIPLE instances of activating his stealth as Kha'zix WHILE the enemy turret is focusing him, and having the turret STOP attacking him.

Comment: I just played a game with a Kha'Zix and his ulti made the two towers at the enemy nexus lose focus and change target, Kha'zix was in tower range the whole time while a super minion started taking the hits.

Comment: @cresh so perhaps my friend wasn't insane?

Comment: It would seem so, my friend and I are are working on confirming if i'm just going insane aswell or if its true

Comment: Ok so I just finished a bot game and experimented with the ulti, I actually managed to get a tower to lose focus on me, its late though so i'm going to bed and uploading it tomorrow. And I took a loss because of it I hope you are happy!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as you don't attack a enemy champion in tower range it will make a tower lose focus.

Comment: Interesting. It looks to be inconsistent, which makes me think this might be a bug.

Comment: I agree, it is a bit sketchy.

Answer (score 6):

Kha'Zix's stealth is no different from any other, and towers can see him just fine.

It will currently also, however, sometimes cause towers to lose focus and attack other targets. This may be a bug.

<strike>Some possibilities:</strike>

- Kha'Zix's ult reduces damage while stealthed (even when he's visible). Reduced turret damage might look like he's not being shot at.
- Was Kha'Zix skirting the edge of the tower? The turret's visible range is just a hair larger than its firing range. If Kha'zix was firing his skill shot from the edge, he would not provoke tower aggro (because the tower couldn't reach him!)
- Your friend is fallible. Perhaps your friend is merely gushing about the new hero! Just because he *thinks* he's avoiding tower shots doesn't mean he actually is.

Comment: Sounds far more likely

Comment: I think the third option is the most likely, however I wanted to give him the benefit of the doubt

Comment: I've also heard my friends comment on the same thing: the true sight does reveal him, but the towers lose aggro. So it's better to just test it.

Comment: @BBz now the real question reveals itself, is this a bug or an intended mechanic?

Comment: Could there be a brief moment between the tower seeing him and then swapping to stealth and then the tower true sight kicking in? Like less time than a human can tell? If you so it could lose sight briefly only to regain it but since it lost it at any time it resets the attack timer?

Answer (score 0):

I believe all stealths do this not just his. I think if you don't attack a champion and other targets are in range it will do the same.

Comment: can you provide some form of proof or a source?